# Web Scraping WSJ Archive with BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to web scraping in general. I have worked with some lxml in the past and I'm now trying to get more knowledge in bs4. Here is what I am doing:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Website to be scraped:
url = 'https://www.wsj.com/news/archive/2020/08/28'

# HTTP Request:
response = requests.get(url)

# Extract text from response:
html_content = response.text

# Make some soup:
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html')

# Extract Data:
for i in soup.find_all("article", {"class":"WSJTheme--story--XB4V2mLz WSJTheme--padding-top-large--2v7uyj-o styles--padding-top-large--3rrHKJPO WSJTheme--padding-bottom-large--2lt6ga_1 styles--padding-bottom-large--2vWCTk2s WSJTheme--border-bottom--s4hYCt0s "}):
  print(i)
```

The reason I am using those tags in the `find_all()` function is because that is what I got from the WSJ website after inspecting the page. The page looks fairly simple, just a bunch of containers with topics, headlines and dates. That's all I need but when I run the code, it does not find anything.

I will greatly appreciate any feedback on this one.

Thanks!

Comment: what you want to extract? title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get information from the page, specify `User-Agent` HTTP header. Without it, the server returns different HTML.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.wsj.com/news/archive/2020/08/28'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

for article in soup.select('article'):
    print(article.span.text)
    print(article.h2.text)
    print(article.p.text)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Slideshow
Chadwick Boseman Played Black Icons, Found Fame With ‘Black Panther’
11:20 PM ET
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
U.S.
George Floyd’s Death Likely Caused by Drug Overdose, Argue Derek Chauvin’s Lawyers
10:59 PM ET
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
U.S.
Chadwick Boseman, Star of ‘Black Panther,’ Dies of Cancer at 43 
10:39 PM ET
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Japan
Abe Will Resign as Japan’s Prime Minister, Citing His Health
10:17 PM ET
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Politics
Thousands March on National Mall, Continuing Racial-Justice Push
10:11 PM ET
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That was a very simple fix. Never came to mind to add the headers.